# restore permissions of ubuntu 10.04 after running "chmod 700 -R /" as root

Tags: permissions, chmod

I have run:

```
chmod 700 -R /
```

with root access on ubuntu 10.04.
Is there any way for recovering from this situation other than reinstall?
Then I again ran:

```
chmod 777 -R /
```

to fix it and now I have lost network access on all users (even root) and lost the permission to even shutdown the system on my regular user. What am I supposed to do? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Good thing you are using 10.04. It is end of life so re-installing is the best option. See it as a lesson and never do it again. By the way: you probably also put sudo in front of it?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're boned =\

If it was just the root you could have fixed it, but running it recursively on everything below it really screwed you.

Time to bust out a live DvD and get to re-installing. Be more careful next time.